# How can I add the ckEditor table plugin?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I downloaded the code from the ckEditor but how can I add the plug in? So far I have added it to the plug in folder but how do I configure it so it's used.

Here's my config set up. I am not sure in particular how to add the button?

```
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'document', groups: ['Source', 'mode', 'document', 'doctools', 'maximize'] },
    { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
    { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection', 'spellchecker'] },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
    { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'justify'] },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'others' }
];

config.extraPlugins = 'insertpre,format,justify,maximize,sourcearea';
```

Comment: I wonder why they haven't given such things in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could just add `Table` to your `config.toolbar`, like :

```
config.toolbar = [
    { name: 'insert', items: [ 'Table' ] }
];
....
```

and it will show the Table button in your editor